# Groovy Scripting with elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

my groovy script is something like this code:

```
def value=DynamicValue     
def Nvalue=NewValue
def field=Fieldvalue
def prod

NewValue=NewValue.toInteger()
prod=doc[''+DynamicValue+''].value*NewValue         
if(._source.doc[''+Fieldvalue+''].value != null) {
    ._source.doc[''+Fieldvalue+''].value=prod
}
```

I am trying to update the value of a field in my elasticsearch index like

```
._source.doc[''+Fieldvalue+''].value=prod
```

where AVG_PRICE_PER_UNIT is a field in my index.

But when i am exceuting it from java i get

```
  "reason" : {
            "type" : "script_exception",
            "reason" : "failed to run file script [fieldScript] using lang [groovy]",
            "caused_by" : {
              "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
              "reason" : "argument type mismatch"
            }

is there any solution??
```

My Java code:

```
Map<String, Object> params = ImmutableMap.of("DynamicValue",AggregateValue_First, "NewValue", AggregateValue_Second, "Fieldvalue",hash); 
try { 
    SearchResponse Se = client.prepareSearch(indexName) 
        .addScriptField("checkValue", new Script("fieldScript", ScriptType.FILE, "groovy", params))
        .execute().actionGet(); 
        System.out.println(Se.toString()); 
} catch(RuntimeException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

my log shows

> ```
>       if (._source.doc[''+Fieldvalue+''] != null) {_source.doc[''+Fieldvalue+''].value=prod}
>      ^
> ```
>
> 1 error ];    at
>   org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService.compile(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:198)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService$ScriptChangesListener.onFileInit(ScriptService.java:549)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService$ScriptChangesListener.onFileChanged(ScriptService.java:580)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.watcher.FileWatcher$FileObserver.onFileChanged(FileWatcher.java:279)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.watcher.FileWatcher$FileObserver.checkAndNotify(FileWatcher.java:131)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.watcher.FileWatcher$FileObserver.updateChildren(FileWatcher.java:215)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.watcher.FileWatcher$FileObserver.checkAndNotify(FileWatcher.java:117)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.watcher.FileWatcher.doCheckAndNotify(FileWatcher.java:70)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.watcher.AbstractResourceWatcher.checkAndNotify(AbstractResourceWatcher.java:44)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService$ResourceMonitor.run(ResourceWatcherService.java:187)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool$LoggingRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:640)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: 895843a31627edca5a53c198e26b4f4b13aa65c5: 26:
>   unexpected token: . @ line 26, column 7.

Comment: Can you show the full query you're running? And maybe share a sample doc and/or mapping.

Comment: It is purely java code ,where i pass the parameters

Comment: What error do you see in the ES logs?

Comment: In your elasticsearch logs, what errors do you see?

Comment: You should preferably update your question with that info in order to make it more legible. Comments are not appropriate for that.

Comment: I would like to see the logs when your script runs and produces the error.

Comment: That log seems irrelevant to your issue. Run your script again and check your logs afterwards. What do you see?

Comment: Just these, when i start the ES i the message that i get in log in status changed to yellow ,after that once i run my script i get only these two errors. P.S. i am running it through eclipse

Comment: I have updated the log result @Val

Comment: Thanks. Can you please show the full script file? What you've shown in your question doesn't match with what the error says.

Comment: It is done @Val  i have posted my script

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your script, change it to this:

```
def value=DynamicValue     
def Nvalue=NewValue
def field=Fieldvalue
def prod

NewValue=NewValue.toInteger()
prod=ctx._source[DynamicValue].value * NewValue         
if(ctx._source[Fieldvalue].value != null) {
    ctx._source[Fieldvalue].value=prod
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Val,but this was the previous case for which i was getting 'argument mismatch exception'.  Forget about this , how do you change the value of a field using a script? can you please tell me?

Comment: What do you mean by "previous case"? This should answer what you have in your question. If you have a different question, feel free to ask another one, but let's not mix two different things together.

Comment: i changed the code ,but still i am getting illegal argument exception

Comment: What error do you get now after changing the script? Update your question with the ES log you're receiving.

Comment: I just get "illegal_argument_exception" , the log seems to be empty, Val, Can you suggest me on how to update the field?

Comment: If you get an illegal_argument_exception your ES logs contains more info. Make sure you check the right log. Try again, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Why have you [created a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700449/inline-script-error) instead of continuing the discussion here?

Comment: Sorry @Val , i thought you wanted the other case that is why, by the way i am using the inline scripting now and i have raised a question on it ,can you help me??

Comment: What about this question? It is no longer current?

Comment: Yes,Shall i remove it?

Comment: It has no big value if you never validated that the answer worked for you.

Comment: It didnt work for me thats why i moved on with update with inline scripting

Comment: I did update my answer, though, after you first comments. The above should work.