# Inline Script error

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I am trying to run the Update api using Inline Scripting ,my code is

```
 client.prepareUpdate("result",typeName, "1")
       .setScript(new  Script("ctx._source.gender=doc['"+AggregateValue_First+"'].value*doc['"+AggregateValue_Second+"'].value",ScriptType.INLINE, null, null))
       .get();
```

When I am executing it , i am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to execute script
```

my log looks like

```
 Caused by: ScriptException[failed to run inline script
 [ctx._source.gender =
 doc['AVG_PRICE_PER_UNIT'].value*doc['NUMBER_OF_UNITS'].value] using
 lang [groovy]]; nested:
 NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[missing_property_exception: No such
property: doc for class: af9b76c11012333a0eeba6af6df35125322f36b8];
    at
 org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:320)
    at
 org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.executeScript(UpdateHelper.java:252)... 14 more



 Caused by: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[missing_property_exception:
 No such property: doc for class:
 af9b76c11012333a0eeba6af6df35125322f36b8]  at
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at
 org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyGuardsFiltersAndSignatures.unwrap(IndyGuardsFiltersAndSignatures.java:177)
    at
 org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:228)
    at
 af9b76c11012333a0eeba6af6df35125322f36b8.run(af9b76c11012333a0eeba6af6df35125322f36b8:1)
    at
 org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript$1.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:313)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
 org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:310)
    ... 15 more
```

Can someone help me with this?

i tried

> client.prepareUpdate("result",typeName,"1").setScript(newScript("ctx._source.gender.value =
>   ctx._source['"+AggregateValue_First+"'].value *
>   ctx._source['"+AggregateValue_Second+"'].value", ScriptType.INLINE,
>   null, null))    .get();

now the error is something like

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.elasticsearch.node). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j
>   system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to execute script  at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.executeScript(UpdateHelper.java:257)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:197)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:80)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:174)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:168)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:66)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.instance.TransportInstanceSingleOperationAction$ShardTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportInstanceSingleOperationAction.java:244)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.instance.TransportInstanceSingleOperationAction$ShardTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportInstanceSingleOperationAction.java:240)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(TransportRequestHandler.java:33)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:75)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.doRun(MessageChannelHandler.java:300)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   ScriptException[failed to run inline script [ctx._source.gender.value
>   = ctx._source['AVG_PRICE_PER_UNIT'].value * ctx._source['5'].value] using lang [groovy]]; nested: AssertionError[BUG! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION:
>   member is private: java.lang.Integer.value/int/getField, from
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface]; nested:
>   NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[illegal_access_exception: member is
>   private: java.lang.Integer.value/int/getField, from
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface];   at
>   org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:320)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.executeScript(UpdateHelper.java:252)
>     ... 14 more Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: BUG! UNCAUGHT
>   EXCEPTION: member is private: java.lang.Integer.value/int/getField,
>   from org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Selector$PropertySelector.chooseMeta(Selector.java:311)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Selector$MethodSelector.setCallSiteTarget(Selector.java:954)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:224)
>     at
>   a45669ea4b74cc2cb4371072fd14ab69cb5dd5f6.run(a45669ea4b74cc2cb4371072fd14ab69cb5dd5f6:1)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript$1.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:313)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:310)
>     ... 15 more Caused by:
>   NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[illegal_access_exception: member is
>   private: java.lang.Integer.value/int/getField, from
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface]    at
>   java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.checkAccess(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.checkField(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectFieldCommon(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectFieldNoSecurityManager(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.unreflectField(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.unreflectGetter(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Selector$PropertySelector.chooseMeta(Selector.java:302)
>     ... 21 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (i.e. use `ctx._source` instead of `doc`):

```
client.prepareUpdate("result",typeName, "1")
   .setScript(new  Script("ctx._source.gender = ctx._source['"+AggregateValue_First+"'] * ctx._source['"+AggregateValue_Second+"']", ScriptType.INLINE, null, null))
   .get();
```

Comment: now i get AssertionError[BUG! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION: member is private: java.lang.Integer.value/int/getField

Comment: Try again with `ctx._source.gender.value` (updated above)

Comment: Still the same @Val

Comment: Can you paste the full error in your question please?

Comment: I have changed  it @Val

Comment: My bad, sorry, remove the `.value` everywhere since we're accessing the source directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Val ,it Worked :) and can you help me with Update by query?

Comment: The thing is ,i am creating this field gender through update i want to create the field for every document in the index,how do i do that?

Comment: Is there an existing question for that?

Comment: No, I will create ,Give me a moment

Comment: See if this answer helps first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038887/update-by-query-in-elasticsearch-using-java

Comment: I have used the updatebyquery jar but i am getting "The type org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.IndicesReplicationOperationRequestBuilder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
  required .class files" for  BulkIndexByScrollResponse

Comment: You're probably missing the main elasticsearch client JAR

Comment: Which is that JAR @VAL?

Comment: This one should do: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.4.0

Comment: Still facing the same issue and btw im using node builder for client

Comment: Feel free to create another question then.

Comment: Hey Val, I have created